# Rare crash when setting a value in an async DispatchQueue

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code in a class that sets a value `last` asynchronously in a `DispatchQueue`:

```
final class Storage {
  ...

  var last: LastItems? {
    get {
      queue.sync { [unowned self] in
        return self._last
      }
    }
    set {
      queue.async { [unowned self] in
        self._last = newValue // crashes here
      }
    }
  }
  private var _last: LastItems?
}

struct LastItems {
  let request: MyRequest
  let myPublisher: PassthroughSubject<MyState, Never>
}

...

// When the presentation completes I do this:
let last = LastItems(
  request: request,
  myPublisher: myPublisher
)
Storage.shared.items.last = last
```

This is called after presentation of a `UIViewController` and is basically storing some items associated with the presentation.

Unfortunately, in some very rare circumstances it crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` at the point of setting `last` (indicated above) with the following stack trace:

```
#0  0x000000018bf86e04 in bool swift::RefCounts<swift::RefCountBitsT<(swift::RefCountInlinedness)1> >::doDecrementSlow<(swift::PerformDeinit)1>(swift::RefCountBitsT<(swift::RefCountInlinedness)1>, unsigned int) ()
#1  0x0000000104b32884 in outlined destroy of MyInfo ()
#2  0x0000000104deb7d8 in outlined assign with take of LastItems? ()
#3  0x0000000104de7a28 in closure #1 in Items.last.setter at /Items.swift:21 // Crash here
#4  0x0000000104bb4044 in thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () ()
#5  0x0000000106444528 in _dispatch_call_block_and_release ()
#6  0x0000000106445d50 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#7  0x000000010644e014 in _dispatch_lane_serial_drain ()
#8  0x000000010644ed6c in _dispatch_lane_invoke ()
#9  0x000000010645cb74 in _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread ()
#10 0x00000001b18348fc in _pthread_wqthread ()
Enqueued from com.apple.main-thread (Thread 1) Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
#0  0x000000010644b0ac in dispatch_async ()
#1  0x00000001a2af80dc in _swift_dispatch_async ()
#2  0x00000001a2af6ed0 in OS_dispatch_queue.async(group:qos:flags:execute:) ()
#3  0x0000000104de7880 in Items.last.setter at MyApp/Items.swift:20
#4  0x0000000104dd8428 in closure #1 in AnyPublisher<>.storeObjects(_:_:) at MyApp/StoreObjectsOperator.swift:28
#5  0x0000000104dd84bc in partial apply for closure #1 in AnyPublisher<>.storeObjects(_:_:) ()
#6  0x000000019c9d8ce4 in Publishers.Map.Inner.receive(_:) ()
#7  0x000000019c9f5570 in Publishers.FlatMap.Outer.receiveInner(_:_:) ()
#8  0x000000019c9f5470 in Publishers.FlatMap.Outer.Side.receive(_:) ()
#9  0x000000019c96a9bc in Future.Conduit.fulfill(_:) ()
#10 0x000000019c96ab34 in Future.Conduit.offer(_:) ()
#11 0x000000019c96ce48 in partial apply for closure #1 in Future.promise(_:) ()
#12 0x000000019c98b068 in ConduitList.forEach(_:) ()
#13 0x000000019c969088 in Future.promise(_:) ()
#14 0x000000019c96cdf8 in partial apply for closure #1 in Future.init(_:) ()
#15 0x0000000104dd6064 in closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in AnyPublisher<>.showView(_:) at MyApp/ShowView.swift:35
#16 0x0000000104e2b2bc in closure #1 in MyViewController.show() at MyApp/MyViewController.swift:485
#17 0x0000000104bb4044 in thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () ()
#18 0x0000000115f9fc84 in -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] ()
#19 0x0000000115fa7d8c in -[_UICurrentContextPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] ()
#20 0x0000000115fa3438 in __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke.88 ()
#21 0x000000011609ce18 in -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] ()
#22 0x0000000116b810dc in -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:] ()
#23 0x0000000116b80e78 in -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] ()
#24 0x0000000116bacd8c in __UIVIEW_IS_EXECUTING_ANIMATION_COMPLETION_BLOCK__ ()
#25 0x0000000116bacff0 in -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] ()
#26 0x0000000116b88a08 in -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] ()
#27 0x0000000116b88e44 in -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] ()
#28 0x0000000116b88f44 in -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] ()
#29 0x0000000187e09320 in CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) ()
#30 0x0000000106445d50 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#31 0x0000000106456808 in _dispatch_main_queue_drain ()
#32 0x00000001064562d4 in _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF ()
#33 0x000000018039a784 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ ()
#34 0x0000000180394de4 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#35 0x0000000180394254 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#36 0x0000000188eb7c9c in GSEventRunModal ()
#37 0x0000000116712ff0 in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#38 0x0000000116716f3c in UIApplicationMain ()
#39 0x000000010897c454 in UIApplicationMain(_:_:_:_:) ()
#40 0x0000000104af7d30 in static UIApplicationDelegate.main() ()
#41 0x0000000104af7cac in static AppDelegate.$main() at MyApp/AppDelegate.swift:11
#42 0x0000000104af7dac in main ()
#43 0x0000000105945514 in start_sim ()
#44 0x00000001056a1e50 in start ()
#45 0xaf21800000000000 in 0xaf21800000000000 ()
```

I can't figure out what's happening here, does anyone know what might be happening? I know this is a long shot but anything's appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that `Storage` is being deallocated before the system starts the setter's async block? You could try using `weak self` instead of `unowned self` in the setter.

Comment: @Rudedog Its impossible because `Storage` is part of a singleton that never gets deallocated and will always be available

Comment: Is `MyInfo` a substructure in `MyState` or perhaps `MyRequest`? You haven't shown any code relating to it, yet it seems to be involved in this. (Note the second row of the call stack)

Comment: Have you tried using sync instead of async for set? I can already see race conditions that could arise from that.